# In Swift, to update a cells contents, should I make a copy of the cell or call tableView.reloadRows for UI updates?

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, uitableview

In Swift, to update a cells contents, should I  make a copy of the cell or call tableView.reloadRows for UI updates?

I have a mass form to fill out which has multiple parts and each part is put inside of a tableView. The cells are all quite active in Contents moving around (UI), but most of the contents remains where it is close to a static cell design.

Is it better practice to grab a copy of the cell and update a label or other random object inside of it directly, or call `tableView.reloadRows(at: [theRow], with: .none)` to update the single object. I understand that it is probably better to do reloadRows if the entire contents of the cell was to change, but if only one label, which is the preferred route?

This directly effects super core functionality of my App. This is happening thousands of times, so understand that I am not asking in complete vain.

I am asking this question because if saving the cell to memory is less work than reloading a tableViewCell than I need a massive rework. I suppose I need to get better with Instruments so I can just write tests to tell me such things. I am trying to maintain a perfect frame rate, so minimizing memory usage is nice.

Example of one of my tableViews:

[image: ![enter image description here]

So for a basic example, when I go to update a label after the slider value changes, do I update the cell from a tableView.reloadRow, or do I hold a copy of the cell to directly update the label?

The biggest reason I began asking this question is that animations get cut short on `tableView.reload`. I finally just want to figure out what the preferred design pattern is in such a scenario.

Comment: Why would it be a good idea to copy a cell? The whole point of table view cells is for them to be reusable so that memory doesn't have to be tied up storing similar cells. How did you implement your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

Comment: If it is a static and you need to change one label, surely just do it directly. It's straightforward and simple, no need to complicate it.

Comment: @AlexS All of my code works as I want it to. I am asking this question because if saving the cell to memory is less work than reloading a tableViewCell than I need a massive rework. I suppose I need to get better with Instruments so I can just write tests to tell me such things.

Comment: @matt any chance I can get your opinion?